# Как добавить в свой проект библиотеку libosmscout?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Как добавить в свой проект библиотеку [libosmscout](http://libosmscout.sourceforge.net/) ? Я использую IDE Qt Creator, у меня операционная система Windows. Пишу я на C++. Можно объяснить как установить её и привести маленький пример использования. Буду благодарен. Сейчас я скачал эту библиотеку

```
$ git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/libosmscout/code libosmscout-code
```

и не понимаю как её дальше подключать и использовать.

Comment: В документации этого не прописано?

Comment: @VTT Я не понимаю как собрать библиотеку, там есть описание но оно мне не понятно . Например : $ mkdir build
  $ cd build
  $ cmake ..
  $ make ЧТО для  cmake .. прописывать тут , если у меня Qt Creator/ Уроков вообще нет

Comment: Эм, эти команды создают папку `build` в текущей папке, заходят в нее, и запускают cmake в исходной папке. `..` - это алиас для доступа к родительской папке. Ну и там явно подразумевается, что пользователь умеет пользоваться cmake. Уроки по cmake следует искать в другом месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачать исходники - это только начало. Вам нужно собрать библиотеку (получить объектные файлы и заголовки) и подключить её к вашему Qt-проекту.

Чтобы собрать придётся самостоятельно покурить инструкцию. Не забудьте при сборке использовать те же флаги компилятора, что используете и в вашем проекте. На выходе получите набор файлов `*.h` и `*.dll/*.lib` для Windows (`*.so` - для Linux).

Устанавливаете библиотеку в нужное вам место.

Подключаете её к сборке вашего проекта. Для этого в pro-файле добавляете:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/your/headers # путь, куда вы положили заголовки вашей библиотеки
LIBS += -L/path/to/your/lib \ # путь, куда вы положили бинарные модули вашей библиотеки
        -lyourlibname # собственно имя подключаемой библиотеки без префикса lib и расширения файла (т.е. для файла librt.so нужно написать -lrt)
```

Comment: Здесь загвоздка, когда собираю библиотеку. Требует указать компилятор. У меня компилятор MinGW и IDE Qt Creator. Нет инструкции, как  собрать для Qt библиотеку или я что то упускаю. В ошибке просят указать компилятор и где установлена Visual Studio:  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

Comment: Документация по [cmake](https://cmake.org/documentation/). При вызове cmake, чтобы он сгенерировал нужные вам сценарии сборки, нужно указать ключ `-G "MinGW Makefiles"`.